# Magento 2 - Mismatched anonymous define()

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I've added a lot of RequireJS code, but know suddenly it does not work anymore. I get an error 'Mismatched anonymous define()' for code that's added from phtml files. This is the code where the error is thrown:

[image: the code where the error is thrown]

This is the error is thrown:

[image: error]

How can this suddenly not work anymore?

#### Update

I think there's something completely off with my JS loading. I get different JS errors each time I load the page:

[image][image][image]

#### Update 2

Thanks to Siarhey Uchukhlebau I found the answer. The real error was thrown by an external script (Tawk.to, a chat client). This error caused all kind of weird errors. I will investigate this problem further to check if we can isolated these kind of script to prevent them from messing with our main script.

Comment: You can find more info about the "Mismatched anonymous define() modules" error in the [requireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html)

Comment: Hi Siarhey, thanks for your comment. I know about this part in the documentation. The weird thing is it worked for a long time, and now it does not work anymore. I've implemented the requirejs functions as shown in the documentation.

Comment: Can you share a link to your dev?

Comment: I can confirm. If you suddenly see alot of JS errors like mentioned here "Mismatched anonymous define()", please check external scripts loading. I had script from cookiebot.com which were responsible for all the errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I can see in the debug error comes from the online chat script:

> https://embed.tawk.to/58f61af6f7bbaa72709c6ddd/default

[image: debug window]

First, try to remove it from your store, clean cache and make sure that error has gone, then I'll recommend you contact their support team.

Comment: Siarhey, that's awesome. This solved all of the weird JS errors. I have two questions that you maybe can answer: 
- How can we debug these errors properly? I see you use the sources tab which I'm known with. But the real error is far away. Is there an easy way to debug this?
- Is there a way we can prevent these issues from external scripts? Maybe isolate them or something, to prevent messing with our RequireJS. Thanks again!

Comment: @Silvan I just move up on the trace of methods call and come to the source where conditions met (`arg[0]` is null) , then during inspecting the `args` I found some info about source class, like specified global variable `$_TAWK_`. Using google i found script with that variable and found some script on your site: chat widget on your site generates that error. I'll recomend you to start debuging from the line where error was thrown and inspect call-stack trace. PS: Take my apology for my English, i don’t have a good command of it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we have faced the require js issue(Mismatched anonymous define()) on the admin side only. This issue was resolved by disabling the **Admin Usage Tracking option to NO**.

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0;
php bin/magento cache:clean;
```

**First please check this value of **admin/usage/enabled** path in the **core_config_data table** and execute the above Magento commands.**

I hope these findings will help others and save time.

[Source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618#issuecomment-1592991014)

Comment: Had the very same issue just today, after not changing anything in that project for a couple of days. So I assume other people will also have this problem today. Personally I just disabled the "Magento_AdminAnalytics" extension completely.

Its a shame that Magento/Adobe would release such a change possibly impacting a large number of vendors and causing huge financial damage due to time invested for figuring out what the issue is. :-(

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0;
php bin/magento cache:clean;

@Jitendra Patel, its works for me.