# Magento 2: Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: magento2

The error occurred in the require([.

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
    // <![CDATA[
        require([  <-- The Error occured here
            'jquery',
            'owlcarousel', 
        ], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#recent-slider").owlCarousel({
                    loop: false,
                    margin: 17,
                    responsiveClass: true,
                    nav: true,
                    dots: false,
                    responsive:{
                        0:{
                            items: 1,
                            nav: true
                        },
                        1024:{
                            items: 3,
                            nav: true
                        },
                        668:{
                            items: 2,
                            nav: true,
                            loop: false
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){return
> function Q(a,o,s){function l(n,e){if(!o[n]){if(!a[n]){var
> t="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!e&&t)return
> t(n,!0);if(d)return d(n,!0);var r=new Error("Cannot find module
> '"+n+"'");throw r.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",r}var
> i=o[n]={exports:{}};a[n][0].call(i.exports,function(e){var
> t=a[n][1][e];return l(t||e)},i,i.exports,Q,a,o,s)}return
> o[n].exports}for(var d="function"==typeof
> require&&require,e=0;e<s.length;e++)l(s[e]);return
> l}({1:[function(e,t){function
> n(e){this.name="RavenConfigError",this.message=e}n.prototype=new
> Error,n.prototype.constructor=n,t.exports=n},{}],2:[function(e,t){var
> l=e(5),n=function(e,r,i){var a=e[r],o=e;if(r in e){var
> s="warn"===r?"warning":r;e[r]=function(){var
> e=[].slice.call(arguments),t=l.safeJoin(e,"
> "),n={level:s,logger:"console",extra:{arguments:e}};"assert"===r?!1===e[0]&&(t="Assertion
> failed: "+(l.safeJoin(e.slice(1),"
> ")||"console.assert"),n.extra.arguments=e.slice(1),i&&i(t,n)):i&&i(t,n…

Comment: see if this is related to you **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177187/magento-2-mismatched-anonymous-define**

Comment: @MohitRane Thanks for the links. It helps

Comment: it was the external js thats causing the error. if anyone is having the same error. Try to load the external js with require. 

ex: require(['url.js']);

Comment: ok I'm adding as an answer since it resolved your issue. Accept my answer so it will help others as well. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Please see below solution, this could be your external js error**

**[Magento 2 - Mismatched anonymous define()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177187/magento-2-mismatched-anonymous-define)**

**Hope it helps.**